# Problema com cookies no php

Tags: php, cookies

Estou tentando gerar um sistema que grava o email da pessoa em um cookie para ele poder adicionar uma lista de imoveis de um site no banco de dados e quando carregar o site através do email dele puxa a lista dos imoveis favoritados.

fiz um form simples que joga para uma pagina o post do email dele.
meu cod que recebe esta da seguinte forma.

```
if(!empty($_POST['Fmail'])){
   setcookie( "meuemail", $_POST['Fmail'], strtotime( '+1 year' ) );
}
```

depois disso ele atualiza a pagina

na pagina do imóvel eu tenho um script simples para validar este cookie

```
echo $_COOKIE['meuemail'];
```

só que sempre fica em branco isso nunca fica preenchido.
Onde estou errando?

Comment: Verifica se tens o índice "Fmail" do $_POST está correcto. Substitui isso por uma string p ex para ver se funciona. De facto, é assim que se define cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> '/' significa que o cookie está disponível em todo o site

```
if(!empty($_POST['Fmail'])){
  setcookie( "meuemail", $_POST['Fmail'], strtotime( '+1 year' ), '/' );
}
```

Comment: show, como q eu faço a verificação se esse cookie existe? com isset ou empty ?

Comment: Pode usar o mesmo if que criou o cookie,  if(!empty($_COOKIE[meuemail])){   echo $_COOKIE[meuemail]; }  em qualquer pagina de qualquer diretório do site.

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez ajudou muito