# Como exibir Cookie em uma outra página

Tags: php

Tenho o código abaixo:
**cookie.php**

```
$d1 =  "27/07/2017"; 
$d2 =  "27/07/2017"; 

setcookie("d1",$d1, (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)));
setcookie("d2",$d2, (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)));

$data1 = $_COOKIE["d1"];
$data2 = $_COOKIE["d2"];

?>
```

Quero exibir o Cookie nesta outra página, mas não consigo:
**index.php**

```
<?php

$data1 = $_COOKIE["d1"];
$data2 = $_COOKIE["d2"];

echo "Período informado: $data1 - $data2";

?>
```

Aparece o seguinte erro: 
**Notice:** Undefined index: d1
**Notice:** Undefined index: d2

Comment: Tente definir o quarto parâmetro de `setcookie` como `"/"`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que tava faltando. Valeu Anderson!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200325/problema-com-cookies-no-php/200333#200333